# css: postion elements flush at top with another element instead of bottom

Tags: css, asp.net

I have 3 elements inline block with each other. The 2 smaller grids are flush with the bottom of the larger chart by default. How can I get them to be flush with the top of the larger chart instead. https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXzPw.png

I would prefer to not have to give an absolute position to each element, unless thats the only way.

all thats applied atm:

```
#smallgrid1, #largechart, #smallgrid2{
       display: inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top` to css if you want to align them to top.

Other options for `vertical-align` which you may want are: `middle, baseline, bottom etc.`

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Answer (score 0):

`#smallgrid1, #largechart, #smallgrid2{
       display: inline-block; 
       vertical-align: top; }`

Answer (score 0):

Hi there you could try this

```
#smallgrid1, #largechart, #smallgrid2{
   display: inline-block; vertical-align: top}
```

Answer (score 0):

If, by default, the elements don't end up aligning themselves towards the top, I would use the `vertical-align` property to position each of the `inline-block` elements to the `top`.

I've created [a simple CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DuwdI) that demonstrates this more clearly. Notice how I style each of the `div` elements on the page:

```
div.element {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; /* aligns each of the divs to the top of the container */
}
```

In this case, the element ids are arbitrarily named `element1`, `element2`, and `element3`, but you would probably name them `smallgrid1`, `largechart`, and `smallgrid2` respectively.